# Play selected music as background music for a game

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a game for android where the user choose music from his library and then it plays on background while the game is running until they fail.

This is the code I have, it plays the song when it's selected, but it doesn't keep playing when I press the OK button

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button openFile = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.openFile);
    openFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }

    });
    Button play = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10){
        Uri uriSound=data.getData();
        play(this, uriSound);
    }
}

private void play(Context context, Uri uri) {

    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing start before the player is prepared, check out this diagram

https://image.slidesharecdn.com/mediaplayer-110716092828-phpapp02/95/android-media-player-9-728.jpg?cb=1310809360

```
private void play(Context context, Uri uri) {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
    }
   });
}}
```

Try something like this.

Comment: I tried this but still it doesn't play the music, maybe it could be a problem with the context?

Comment: I don't think so , it would have said context is null if so , try adding this line after the MediaPlayer.create(...) line => player .prepareAsync();

Comment: It seems that it doesn't execute what is inside of onPrepared

Comment: Got it, now it works but it's giving me this error     `Unable to create media player`    
  `setDataSource: SecurityException! uri=content://media/external/audio/media/36741
                                                                   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/36741 from pid=24008, uid=10234 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

Comment: Now it plays, it needed ask for permission at runtime. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to implement an OnClickListener for the play button.

```
Button play = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        play(this, uriSound);
    }

});
```

To get urisound, convert it from a local variable in onActivityResult to a field of the class MainActivity

```
private Uri uriSound;
```

Don't forget to change the code in onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10){
       uriSound=data.getData();
       play(this, uriSound);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This solves my problem of saving the route of the song, but still it doesn't play when I press the play Button